# How to include tools/commands in yocto image recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I have a question regarding including different tools into Yocto image recipe. Currently I am building image recipe for my Avenger96 board. I have created a base image and it runs fine on the device. But when I try to do `sgdisk` after booting it says `-sh: sgdisk: command not found`. I understand that these commands are not available by default and need to install it.

But I am not sure how to do it given my board is not connected to internet. Can I include these commands/tools in image recipe? I want to use some other commands like `ufw`, etc but I have same issue with them too.

Can someone please let me know how to do this?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Yocto as build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sgdisk` is present under recipe: `meta/recipes-devtools/fdisk/gptdisk_xx.bb`

For `xx` it depends on your poky version.

For dunfell this is the recipe [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/fdisk/gptfdisk_1.0.4.bb?h=dunfell).

`ufw` is present in `meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/ufw`

So, make sure `meta-openembedded/meta-networking` is present in your `bblayers.conf` and to include both of them add the following line to `local.conf` or to your custom image file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gptfdisk ufw"
```

If you still do not find sgdisk try `gptdisk-sgdisk`.

If you want to add any recipe in the future, try to look for it in the official yocto git repositories in this [link](https://git.yoctoproject.org/).

It is not recommended to add tools manually into the board, unless you are in the development process and you need to gain time, so here are some ideas for you:

- Create an image for development that includes all dev features (gcc, g++, cmake, ..etc)
- Include `git` and other fetching tools
- Clone the tool's source code and compile it in the board
- Or: `bitbake` the recipe with Yocto and copy the output binary directly to the image via ssh or other ways.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. But when I include `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gptdisk "` in my image recipe, I get `ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'gptdisk'. Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['gptdisk']`. The `poky/meta` is included in `bblayers.conf`. Tried with `gptdisk-sgdisk` but I get same error.

Comment: what poky branch are you using ?

Comment: Dunfell. And `meta/recipes-devtools/fdisk/gptfdisk_1.0.4.bb` is available. Is it `gptdisk` or `gptfdisk`?

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake, it is `gptfdisk`, I fixed my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's working now.